# Leaflet map redundancy

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to add redundancy to map POI since quite a long time for a leaflet map i use on this page : http://worldisbeautiful.net/carte/

I'm sorry if my english isn't clear, that's probably why i'm having hard time to find a solution. See when you zoom out on this map, you have multiple world maps side by side but the POI are only on one map. Is there a way to have POI on each world maps, same positions ?

I understand there is an option `nowrap` to avoid multiple world maps but i like the idea of moving from left/right and having the earth rotating not just a plain map.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a current leaflet limitation. See [this support request](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1945)

I think a workaround might be to replicate the markers with +360 degrees to wrap around the world.